# Displaying button inside componentsJoinedByString

Tags: iphone

i have a question that i want to put a button instead of @"/n"  ie,@"uibutton"

```
BibleIphoneAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BibleIphoneAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     NSArray *allVerses = [appDelegate.biblearray valueForKey:@"verseNumber"];
    _bibleDesciption.text = [allVerses componentsJoinedByString:@"/n"];
```

verseNumber contains verses of the bible ,my need is to put a button in between verses.I hope u understand my question.plase help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, `componentsJoinedByString:` returns a `NSString*`. You'll need to create and add buttons manually. I suggest using a `UIScrollView` and add each verse to a separate `UILabel`, and after each label add a `UIButton`. You'll have to calculate the positions where to add each label and button inside the scrollview, and to set the scrollview contentSize accordingly.

Comment: @babbidi can u explain in detail?please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so it probably contains some bugs, but should help you get started.

```
    // set these as members of your class
NSMutableArray *_versesLabels;          // used for easier access when a button is pressed
NSMutableArray *_versesButtons;
/*IBOutlet */UIScrollView *_scrollView;

    // your initialization/loading method
// <..set up _scrollView as you wish>
int labelWidth = 300; // change this as you wish
int buttonWidth = 100, buttonHeight=30;
int padding = 5;      // space between labels/buttons from the scrollView
BibleIphoneAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BibleIphoneAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *allVerses = [appDelegate.biblearray valueForKey:@"verseNumber"];
int currentY = padding;
for(int i=0; i<[allVerses count]; i++){
        // create and place the label
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl.text = [allVerses objectAtIndex:i];
    // <..customize the label - fonts, colors etc>
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;  // in case you have verses that don't fit in a single line
    CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth, 500)];
    lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, currentY, labelWidth, size.height);
    [_scrollView addSubView:lbl];
    [_versesLabels addObject:lbl];
    [lbl release];
    currentY=currentY + lbl.frame.size.height + padding;
        // create and place the button
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, currentY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    btn.tag = i;
    // <..customize the button - fonts, colors etc>
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(pressVerse:) event:UIEventTouchUpInside];
    [_scrollView addSubView:btn];
    [_versesButtons addObject:btn];
    [btn release];
    currentY=currentY + btn.frame.size.height + padding;
}
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, currentY)];


-(void)pressVerse:(UIButton *)b{
    verseIndex = b.tag;
    UILabel *verseLabel = [_verseLabels objectAtIndex:verseIndex];
    // <..do whatever you want when a button is pressed>
}
```

Comment: if you want to add buttons between verses you should use labels instead of textview. It might be possible with a textview as well, but it will be harder.

Comment: as I mentioned, I haven't tested it, so it has some bugs. It's also not complete (e.g you have to set the scrollview). If you get any other errors I'm sure you can find them over the internet with a simple search. For the touchupinside error use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Comment: are you setting up the buttons? At `// <..customize the button - fonts, colors etc>` you should set the button title, customize its look etc. (e.g: `[btn setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal]`).

Comment: In this case you need to place them in a tableview. For each verse you need to create a `UITableViewCell` with a label and a button (or you can use a default cell with its label and the disclosure button, or without button, to act when pressed). There's still a lot of memory to be used with 31000 verses, so you might need use pagination.

Comment: you can customize the table so it doesn't separate the cells.

Comment: yea i had done this ,i remove the seperator from the tableview.but the verses are in /n form.this is not allowed.it must seems like the bible application (olivetree)